# Arrow function to avoid bind

Tags: javascript, class, bind

```
var world = {
  animals: {},
  add_animal: function(options) {
    this.animals[options.name] = {
      name: options.name,
      sound: options.sound,
      actions: {},
      add_action: function(action_name, action_function) {
        this.actions[action_name] = action_function.bind(this);
      }
    }
  }
};

world.add_animal({name: "dog", sound: "bark"});
world.animals.dog.add_action("speak", function() {
  alert("I am a " + this.name + ". I " + this.sound + ".");
});

world.animals.dog.actions.speak();
```

This is a simplified version of a script I wrote a few years ago, which I'd like to update. It creates a world object, with a collection of animals and an add_animal method. Each animal has an add_action method. I'd appreciate some advice on two things.

1. add_action uses bind so "this" refers to the animal within the action function - is there a way to do this with an arrow function => so there's no need for bind?
2. I figured there'll only ever be one "world" so that's why I started with an object literal for world, rather than making world a class. Is there another "best practice" way this could be done, perhaps using classes? If so, is there any real advantage in doing it another way?

Comment: *I started with an object literal for world, rather than making world a class* If it's only going to be a single object, I'd highly prefer a plain object over a class, there's less overhead and syntax noise

Comment: It's not possible to change binding of `this` in an arrow function.

Comment: Well, I just thought I wouldn't need to change the binding of `this` at all if I use an arrow function - one of the advantages of an arrow function is it doesn't change the value of `this`.

Comment: What I'm really asking is, instead of using `this.actions[action_name] = action_function.bind(this);` what's the syntax for using an arrow function instead?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. add_action uses bind so "this" refers to the animal within the action function - is there a way to do this with an arrow function => so there's no need for bind?

Not if you want to use `this` within the action function to refer to the animal, no.

> 2. I figured there'll only ever be one "world" so that's why I started with an object literal for world, rather than making world a class. Is there another "best practice" way this could be done, perhaps using classes? If so, is there any real advantage in doing it another way?

If `world` is a singleton, there's usually no need to do anything other than what you've done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually, `this` within the action function refers to the animal. I'm just wondering if the action function can be assigned to a property of `actions` using `=>` so there's no need for `bind`.

Comment: @TheRatman - Sorry -- that's *twice* I misread the question. :-) Fixed.